# C# get mail and its attachment from outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I've made program which one of the purposes is to open OutLook client where user can write his email, add attachments etc. After sending I want to get all attachments which were added to email, as well as all email in my program.
 I tried to handle close event

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)email.oMsg).Close += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler(GetAttachmentsInfo);
```

and then

```
    if (email.oMsg.Attachments.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment at in email.oMsg.Attachments )
        { attachments.Add(at); }
    }



     email is OutlookEMail
oMsg is Email Item
attachments is List<Attachment>
```

but when I close client Attachment throws exception that cannot find object. as well as these in List.

I know that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment is not a file, but only something like path to this file containing it name and size. 
So question : is it possible to save attachments after client is closed in my program?
(Without using Email.SaveAttachments os SaveEmail methods, because it uses time and computer space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two other options you could try:

#### 1. You could listen for `MailItem` additions to the `SentItems` Folder via [`Folder.ItemAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemsevents_event.itemadd.aspx).

```cs
Outlook.Folder sentItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Outlook.Folder;
sentItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(GetAttachmentsInfo);
```

#### 2. You could attach to the [`MailItem.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866779.aspx) event.

```cs
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)MailItem).Send  += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(GetAttachmentsInfo);
```